# Why is there an error saying I haven't defined the function "is_even"?

Tags: function, python-2.7, control-flow

```
def is_even(answer):
    answered = X % 2 ==0
    if answer ==  answered:
        return "yep"
    else:
        return "nope"
```

the instructions are:
Write a function called is_even that takes one input, x, and returns the string "yep" if the input is even and "nope" otherwise. You do not need to call the function.

Comment: What's in the variable `X`?

Comment: I'm not an python expert, but the if statement looks wrong to me: `answered` is already a boolean type containing the check result.

Comment: Please post the *complete* (relevant) code and the *exact* failure indicator. While the function will go KABOOM when you run it, it should not result in an error along the lines of "haven't defined the function". I suspect that, perhaps, you are trying to use `is_even` somewhere *above* in the file? Remember that Python *does not hoist* function definitions.

Comment: I'm just dumb. I figured out where I went wrong.  Thanks for the tips on X and that "answered" is a boolean.

Comment: You're not dumb, just inexperienced. Although experience doesn't necessarily keep you from being dumb once in a while. It's all part of the joy of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a compile error, as you never introduce `X`. Also, you should read the instructions again. It clearly says what the input should be (`x`). So the method should start like the following:

```
def is_even(x):
  if ...:
    return "yep"
  else:
    return "nope"
```

Comment: It will still create the function with an unbound identifier, even if running it will go KABOOM. The OP indicates the error is "haven't defined the function" ..